# rails array output strange format in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

anyone seen this array error before?
I have a helper method that returns an array. In development mode on my laptop it returns the array in an expected format:

```
var fire = 
[[1349083353000, 8.860000000000582], [1349085153000, 19.779999999999745],
[1349086953000, 20.289999999999964], [1349088753000, 29.850000000000364], 
[1349090553000, 3.7999999999992724]];
```

BUT same code in production returns a strange array format:

```
var fire = 135175422800015.5135175602800020.0135175782800018.99135175962800012.33135176142800019.13135176322800029.55135176502800020.13135176682800077.34
```

I have tried checking the output in rails console on either machine and the production output the same weird array format. I have created a new array from within rails console on production and it works as expected to output the correct format of array.

Anyone seen this bit of weirdness?

```
Rails version:3.2.8
Ruby Version:1.9.3p-125
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to convert a ruby array into javascript code? Can you show the code?

Comment: yes I am doing exactly that. My code in my view is like this 

<script type="text/javascript">
 var waters = <%= getWaterSamples.to_json %>
 var fires = <%= getFireSamples.to_json %>

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

  initChart(fires,waters);
 });
</script>

getFireSamples is a helper that just fetches data from the database and returns as a ruby array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably developing on Ruby 1.9 and deploying on Ruby 1.8. The default behaviors for treating arrays are different.

In Ruby 1.8 `array.to_s` is equivalent to `array.join('')`.

In Ruby 1.9 `array.to_s` is equivalent to `array.inspect`.

If you want the proper behavior on both, and you're using JavaScript, you might want to render it as JSON using `array.to_json` instead.

Comment: You are right. It was the json that was required. Thanks. I dont understand why my server is running on Ruby 1.8.7. I had suspected before that this was the case after experimenting my code in rails console in both versions and seeing the strange array behaviour. I have wrapped up my unicorn with an rvm wrapper and cant see anywhere else where it is not defined...